# ¿Como obtener datos sin saltos de línea?

Tags: mysql, select, csv, salto-de-linea

Tengo conocimientos muy básicos de bases de datos, disculpadme si meto la pata...

En una bbdd X, existe una tabla Y, con un campo llamado 'Z' que es del tipo longtext.

Para obtener el csv, se ejecuta lo siguiente:

```
mysql -u root -p -e "Select * from exp_tickets" bitnami_redmine > exp_tickets.csv
```

Cuando me llega en csv el resultado de volcar la tabla, para poder explotar los datos, veo estos caracteres \n,\r,\t,... entre el texto.

Ejemplo:' \r\nBuenos días,  \r\n \r\nCuando podáis me subís este fichero donde siempre.\r\n

Me han informado que no es posible modificar la bbdd para eliminarlos ahí directamente, pero necesitaría obtener el texto sin esos caracteres ¿Podríais ayudarme a conseguirlo?

Además, sería posible mostrar los primeros 20 caracteres sin esos saltos de línea?

Disculpad si no me explico bien, tengo conocimientos limitados:

```
CREATE TABLE `issues` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tracker_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `project_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `description` longtext,
  `due_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `assigned_to_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `priority_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fixed_version_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `author_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lock_version` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `done_ratio` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `estimated_hours` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `root_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lft` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rgt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_private` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `rt_identifier` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rt_wbs` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `closed_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `risk_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
```

Entre las distintas tablas, existe una tabla 'issues' con varios campos. Uno de ellos 'description'(longtext) que es en el que veo los caracteres \n,\r, etc en el csv.
Con esto se genera la vista:

```
Drop view if exists exp_tickets;
create view exp_tickets as(
select iss.id as id_ticket,
iss.subject as asunto,
(select concat (firstname,' ',lastname) as Autor from users u where u.id=iss.author_id) as autor,
(select concat (firstname,' ',lastname) as Asignado from users u where u.id=iss.assigned_to_id) as asignado,
(select name from issue_categories ic where ic.id=iss.category_id) as categoria,
(select name from issue_statuses istd where istd.id=iss.status_id) as estado,
iss.created_on as creado,
iss.closed_on as cierre,
iss.priority_id as prioridad,
(select name from trackers t where t.id=iss.tracker_id) as tipo
iss.description as descripcion
iss.description as descripcion, SUBSTR(descripcion,1,20)
from issues iss
where created_on >= '2021-01-01')
```

Querría obtener limpio el campo description, y sus primeros 20 caracteres

Gracias.
Un saludo

Comment: Hola JRS. Por favor, utiliza la opción [edit] y agrega el código que has desarrollado para leer el CSV

Comment: No he desarrollado nada para leer el csv, lo estoy viendo desde un editor de texto.

Comment: Entonces, ¿desarrolaste código para crear el CSV? Si es así, agregalo en tu pregunta.

Comment: He añadido la línea que se usa para obtener el csv, pero no la he desarrollado yo, no tengo ese conocimiento

Comment: Debes mostrar un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento, y el problema _específico_ que has tenido. [es.so] debe ser siempre tu último recurso: el sitio no es del tipo _hagan esto por mí_.

Comment: @JRS ¿exactamente que campo de la consulta tiene los saltos de línea? Porque `Select *` devuelve todos los campos y necesitariamos saber exactamente cuales son todos campos y o cuales son los que necesitas "limpiar".

Comment: He añadido más información a la pregunta, a ver si con eso os hacéis una idea de lo que tenemos y lo que necesito. Muchas gracias por la atención

Answer (score 1):

Para remover los caracteres `\n`, `\r` y `\t` podes utilizar la función [`REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

#### Ejemplo:

```sql
SELECT
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(iss.description, '\r', ''), '\n', ''), '\t', '') as descripcion
FROM from issues iss
```

A esto lo podes aplicar en la consulta que crea la vista `exp_tickets` (*siempre y cuando no afecte a otras funciones/herramientas del sistema*)

#### Ejemplo:

```sql
Drop view if exists exp_tickets;
create view exp_tickets as(
  select 
    iss.id as id_ticket,
    iss.subject as asunto,
    (select concat (firstname,' ',lastname) as Autor from users u where u.id=iss.author_id) as autor,
    (select concat (firstname,' ',lastname) as Asignado from users u where u.id=iss.assigned_to_id) as asignado,
    (select name from issue_categories ic where ic.id=iss.category_id) as categoria,
    (select name from issue_statuses istd where istd.id=iss.status_id) as estado,
    iss.created_on as creado,
    iss.closed_on as cierre,
    iss.priority_id as prioridad,
    (select name from trackers t where t.id=iss.tracker_id) as tipo,
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(iss.description, '\r', ''), '\n', ''), '\t', '') as descripcion,
    SUBSTR(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(iss.description, '\r', ''), '\n', ''), '\t', ''), 1, 20) as descripcion_corta
  from issues iss
    where created_on >= '2021-01-01'
);
```

***PD:** Revisa bien la consulta porque al copiar la original encontre campos repetidos y errores de sintaxis.*

Comment: Ok, gracias Marcos. Lo pruebo y te digo.
¿Sería posible mostrar también los primeros 20 caracteres de la descripcion? He probado con la función substring (de ahí a lo mejor los errores de sintaxis) pero no me ha funcionado

Comment: ¿Necesitas que el campo `descripcion` tuviera solo los 20 primeros caracteres o quisieras obtenerlos como otro campo? Si es en otro campo, ¿que nombre quisieras que tenga?

Comment: Me gustaría que saliera en otro campo, por ejemplo descripcion_corta

Comment: Acabo de actualizar mi respuesta. Espero este completa. Saludos!

Comment: Devuelve este error:

Error 1064 (42000) at line 71: Yoy have an error inyour SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REPLACE, '\n',''),'\t','') as desc' at line 12.

¿Me podrías ayudar a depurarlo?

Comment: Tiene bastantes líneas, y no consigo copiarla aquí. ¿Hay alguna manera de que pueda adjuntarla o enviártela?

Comment: @JRS podes crear un [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) y pasar el link por aca

Comment: https://pastebin.com/kEJetNdD

Comment: @JRS https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRGjG.png y https://i.stack.imgur.com/3M1c3.png

Comment: @JRS ¿anduvo? Si te funciono, considera votar la respuesta y/o marcarla como aceptada. Saludos!